# Python element-wise vectorised boolean operations to classify image pixels based on their colour

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, numpy

I have an RGB image which I am loading into a 2D array using PIL

```
img = Image.open(path)
imgData = numpy.array(img)
```

I need to efficiently translate this into a 2D array of RGB tuples (in some sense a 3D array) the same size containing a rough 'classification' of each pixel - 'red', 'green', 'white' or 'other' - at each index based on which 'colour region' they lie within. This is for purposes of image recognition.

My current implementation uses a element-wise for loop but is very slow (an 8MP image takes 1+ minutes):

```
for i in range(cols): # for every col
    for j in range(rows): # for every row
        r,g,b = imgData[i,j]

        if b > 220:     # white
            n = 3
        elif r > 230:   # red
            n = 2
        else:           # green
            n = 1

        mapData[i,j] = n
```

(I realise that the order of the if statements here affects the precedence of the classifications - this is not a major issue for now although I would prefer to define the colour spaces exclusively)

I am running Python 3.6.4 and happy to use NumPy or not. Having done a bunch of research, it seems like there are a number of faster and more 'pythonic' and vectorised ways to do this but I have not been able to get any working.

Any help would be much appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's a 2D array? An RGB image is usually 3D.

Comment: Correct - I suppose it is technically 3D. I said 2D because it is a 2D array of tuples containing the 3 RGB values (which I would imagine are not strictly part of the array?)

Comment: Why is `b > 220:     # white`? There are better criteria for white - e.g. if `b`, `r`, and `g` all are high values. As of now you'll be catching both white and blue with this method.

Comment: it is 3d, each pixel in  `imgData[i,j]` has 3 values  `r,g,b`

Comment: Either use  @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's proposal or solve this with np.where

Comment: @droooze Very true - this was just me trying to remove any unnecessary comparison as there is no blue expected in this particular scenario. The actual definitions of the colour regions are fairly irrelevant to the question though, so you should be able to ignore that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `np.where` makes this pretty fast.

```
mapData = np.where(imgData[:,:,2] > 220, 3, np.where(imgData[:,:,0]>230, 2, 1))
```

But when applying this to a picture the only results where ones. Did I miss anything or should the cases be made in a different way?

Comment: That's great, very fast and no it seems to be producing exactly what I need so I don't think you missed anything. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm as of the moment can be captured like this:

```
r, g, b = imgData[...,0], imgData[...,1], imgData[...,2]
mapData = np.ones_like(r, dtype=int)
mapData[r > 230] = 2
mapData[b > 220] = 3
```

Note the order of operations in assigning these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Colour classification is usually done by treating RGB colours as vectors. Normalize each one to the magnitude, then find the distance to your target colour.

For example, the skin detector in [smartcrop.js](https://github.com/jwagner/smartcrop.js/) works like this (using [pyvips](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyvips)):

```
def pythag(im):
    return sum([x ** 2 for x in im]) ** 0.5

skin = [0.78, 0.57, 0.44]
score = 1 - pythag(img / pythag(img) - skin)
```

Now `score` is a float image with values in 0 - 1 which is 1 for pixels most likely to be skin-coloured. Note that it ignores brightness: you'll need another rule to chop off very dark areas.

In your case I guess you'd need an array set of target vectors, then compute all the colour probabilities, and finally label the output pixel with the index of the highest-scoring vector. Something like:

```
import sys
import pyvips

def pythag(im):
    return sum([x ** 2 for x in im]) ** 0.5

def classify(img, target):
    return 1 - pythag(img / pythag(img) - target)

# find [index, max] of an array of pyvips images
def argmax(ar):
    if len(ar) == 1:
        return [0, ar[0]]
    else:
        index, mx = argmax(ar[:-1])
        return [(ar[-1] > mx).ifthenelse(len(ar) - 1, index),
                (ar[-1] > mx).ifthenelse(ar[-1], mx)]

skin = [0.78, 0.57, 0.44]
red = [1, 0, 0]
green = [0, 1, 0]
targets = [red, green, skin] 

# we're not doing any coordinate transformations, so we can stream the image
img = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1], access="sequential")

scores = [classify(img, x) for x in targets]
index, mx = argmax(scores)

index.write_to_file(sys.argv[2])
```

(plug: pyvips is typically 2x or 3x faster than numpy and needs much less memory)